# What is the difference between the usage of pointer in the following declarations?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
char *array[size];
char (*aPointer)[size];
```

I'm pretty new to C++ and currently I'working on an assignment.And I noticed there are two different(maybe?) use of pointer.
Can anyone please tell me what are the difference between them?
Thank you

Comment: One is an array of pointers. The other is a pointer to an array. For a full explanation, see your C++ book. C++ type system is fairly complex, and cannot be fully described in one or two sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *array[size]` declares an array of `size` pointers to `char`s.

`char (*aPointer)[size]` declares a pointer to an array of `size` `char`s.

Just for the sake of completeness, there's also `char *cPointer`, which declares a pointer to a `char`, which could be the first one in an array.  The difference between that and `aPointer` is a semantic one.  The memory layout will be identical.  For example, `aPointer + 1` will return a pointer that points to a location `size` bytes after the one pointed to by `aPointer`, while `cPointer + 1` will return a pointer that points to a location one byte after the one pointed to by `cPointer`.

So `char *array[size]` declares something like this:

```
 array      +--------+
+------+    | a char |
| a[0] +--->+--------+
+------+
| a[1] +--->+--------+
+------+    | a char |
| ...  |    +--------+
+------+
```

Of course, each of the `char`s pointed to could be the first element of an array as well:

```
 array      +--------+--------+--------+
+------+    | a char | a char |  ...   |
| a[0] +--->+--------+--------+--------+
+------+
| a[1] +--->+--------+--------+--------+
+------+    | a char | a char |  ...   |
| ...  |    +--------+--------+--------+
+------+
```

`char (*aPointer)[size]` declares something like this:

```
 aPointer
+--------+    +--------+
|        +--->+ a char |
+--------+    +--------+
              | a char |
              +--------+
              |  ...   |   aPointer + 1
              +--------+    +--------+
                        <---+        |
                            +--------+
```

`char *cPointer` could declare something like this:

```
 cPointer
+--------+    +--------+
|        +--->+ a char |   cPointer + 1
+--------+    +--------+    +--------+
              | a char +<---+        |
              +--------+    +--------+
              |  ...   |
              +--------+
```

Note that in all of those examples, the pointers don't initially point to anything.  You have to point them at something yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your nice/clean explanation ... two more question: is it possible to assign some values to the first case ? Also, when I set char* something[] as my function parameter, it pops up that it is a char** which is a 2d array ?

Comment: `char**` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.  That pointer could be a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to `char`s, each of which could be a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`s.  It doesn't have to be though.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what you mean by "_is it possible to assign some values in the first case?_".  Of course you can: `array[0] = &someChar`.

Comment: Hello, saying that was because when I tried to assign a value to it, it showed me a seg fault.      array[i][j] = static_cast<char>(45) where 0<=i<10 and 0<=j<5,array was passed by  char* something[]....  and that's why i said that.

Comment: As I mentioned in the note at the end of the answer, the pointers don't initially point to anything.  `array[i]` is a pointer that can point to a `char`, but you have to create a `char` and point to it.

Answer (score 0):

The first declares an array of `size` pointers to `char`. The second declares a pointer to an array of `size` elements of type `char`.

You can think of it as the `[]` operator binding more strongly than `*`. Start reading declarations like this one at the identifier and work your way outwards. In the first case, we see the identifier `array`. Next to it we have `[]` as well as `*`. The `[]` binds more strongly than `*`, so it applies first. Thus, `array` is an array of something. Next applies the `*`, so `array` is an array of pointers to something. The only thing that's left is the type specifier `char`, thus `array` is an array of pointers to `char`. The second case works analogously, only there we have parentheses which force the `*` to apply before the `[]`.